# Java SE 11 String Final Variable with Ternary Operator Does Not Count as a Constant Variable in Switch Case Expression

Tags: string, eclipse, switch-statement, java-11, constant-expression

I encountered a problem that the following code doesn't work. I ran the code in **Java SE 11 (11.0.8), Eclipse 2020-06, Windows 10**.

---

**Use String Final Variable with Ternary Operator: Doesn't work**

```java
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String switchVar = "abc";
        final String caseStr = true ? "abc" : "def";    
        switch (switchVar) {
            case caseStr: System.out.println("Doesn't work");
        }
    }
}
```

It has a compile time error: `java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: case expressions must be constant expressions`.

---

However, according to [JLS §4.12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) and [JLS §15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28), the String type can be a final variable and ternary operator can also be counted as constant expression.

> A constant variable is a final variable of **primitive type** or type **String** that is initialized with a constant expression.

> A constant expression is an expression denoting a value of primitive type or a String that does not complete abruptly and is composed using only the following:
>
> ...
>
> - The ternary conditional operator ? :
> - Simple names that refer to constant variables

---

I did some more tests which showed either one of these points works if not combined together.

**Directly use constant expression as case constant: No Problem**

```java
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String switchVar = "abc";
        switch (switchVar) {
            case true ? "abc" : "def": System.out.println("works");
        }
    }
}
```

**Use String constant variable without ternary operator: No Problem**

```java
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String switchVar = "abc";
        
        final String VAR_A = "a";
        final String VAR_BC = "bc";
        final String CASE = VAR_A + VAR_BC;
        
        switch (switchVar) {
            case CASE : System.out.println("works");
        }
    }
}
```

**Use int with ternary operator instead of String: No Problem**

```java
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int switchVar = 10;
        final int CASE = 3 > 2 ? 10 : 0;
        
        switch (switchVar) {
            case CASE : System.out.println("works");
        }
    }
}
```

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing It is `=` instead of `==` because this is an assignment. The String `caseStr` is evaluated as "abc".

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? `javac` of version 7 to 14 compiles this just fine.

Comment: @Holger Yes, I'm using Eclipse 2020-06.

Comment: Seems like a bug in the Eclipse compiler. `javac` handles this fine.

Comment: @JornVernee and @ Holger, I tried javac from JDK, and yes, it worked. I always thought eclipse use the javac from the JDK directly, but seems like not...

Comment: Eclipse has its own compiler and doesn't use javac. You can report bugs [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/) I see there was another switch bug fixed recently.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks, I will report this bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With kindly help of others, it is sure now this is a bug of eclipse.

I have reported the bug to eclipse. ([Bugzilla – Bug 566332](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=566332))

Comment: Could you please add a link to the bug you reported?

Comment: @howlger, I've added the bug link.

Comment: Thanks for reporting.